# Compare values in MS Word Table Columns, merge cells and delete duplicate values

Tags: vba, ms-word

I originaly posed this problem in May 2017 in the Microsoft Community where I used to modify a table structure using this code:

```
Sub TableDateCleaner()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim r As Long, bFit As Boolean
  With ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
    bFit = .AllowAutoFit
    .AllowAutoFit = False
    For r = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
      If Trim(Split(.Cell(r, 1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)) = _
         Trim(Split(.Cell(r - 1, 1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)) Then
           .Cell(r, 1).Range.Delete
           .Cell(r, 1).Merge .Cell(r - 1, 1)
           .Cell(r, 2).Merge .Cell(r - 1, 2)
      End If
    Next
    With .Range.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "^p"
      .Replacement.Text = ", "
      .Format = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    AllowAutoFit = bFit
    .Rows.HeightRule = wdRowHeightAuto
  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Call LowerCaseAfterComma 'Call next Macro so formatting done in one process
End Sub
```

However, my client is now using different software to produce multiple tables and this macro was originally used for the 2nd named table hence **ActiveDocument.Tables(2)**. Having identified the new table as the 6th named table I modified the code and replaced it with **ActiveDocument.Tables(6)**.

Although I modified the macro to this effect I now get a **‘Runtime Error 5941 The Requested Member of the Collection Does Not Exist’** and the code starting at 'If Trim....' is highlighted in yellow where the error is.  So, I am assuming that it is looking for an object in ActiveDocument.Tables that does not exist any more, which sounds weird but I am at loss to what that is.

I am only a part-time coder so I would like some pointers as to where I may be going wrong. I am using Word 2016.

Answer (score 0):

The code should work exactly the same regardless of which table you're concerned with, provided you specify the correct table index (e.g. 6 instead of 2) and the table structure is the same (i.e. two columns per row). Apart from your code's lack of structure, the only error I can see is that AllowAutoFit = bFit lacks the beginning period (i.e. .AllowAutoFit = bFit). Ideally, you'd also have Call LowerCaseAfterComma *before* Application.ScreenUpdating = True.

Comment: Before I received your answer I realised my client had provided me with a different structured table/template which included two extra rows with no text in some cells and text in others.  This was what was causing the error as the code was looking for an entry in the cell and I only noticed it at the last moment.

I managed to write some code to split those cells at that point and voila the TableDateCleaner routine worked! 

Thankyou though for the extra tips for editing the original code.